# I moved my codeigniter webapp to the test server and now I am not getting any data inserted into my tables?

Tags: php, mysql, configuration, codeigniter-2

I worked on a codeigniter webapp locally then everything was smooth and fine now for testing purpose I moved the app to the test server now no data is getting inserted into the database. What could be the possible reason? 
What are the things that could go wrong for error of this kind.

I know its difficult to pinpoint but I just want a list of checks that I should do.
I have checked the database configuration file.

My application is in codeigniter, OS is ubuntu.

Comment: Enable the profiler (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/profiling.html). It will provide you with lots of useful information.

Answer (score 2):

Check:
the user has permission to execute insert.

you can try to put mysql_error(). For check the problema

Comment: Thanks, I mean the code is generating the query and inserting into the table.

Comment: In CI, all config are in http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html make sure you file are ok in the server. Make sure you are using default tag

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the usual checking of the Database configuration what is imperative that the local database tables should have same fields as the test server.

This is not the only check but one among several possiilities.